# Where can I find examples of Material Design Animated Icons?

Tags: android, material-design

These days, I am interested in Material Design Animated Icons.

So I tried to make the icons in the url below.

https://material.io/design/iconography/animated-icons.html#usage

But I can't find examples :(

So, Could you tell me where I can see the example?

plz..

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it

Comment: refer https://stories.uplabs.com/animated-icons-on-android-ee635307bd6

Comment: @Redman Thank you. But, I wanted to know if there was an example or not. Next time, I will post my problem more clear. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recomend you [this page](https://shapeshifter.design/) for create your own animated SVG files. Just see how it work a SVG(check this [blog](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/understanding-vectordrawable-pathdata-commands-in-android-d56a6054610e)) because you'll work with the components of your vectors. Don't worry it's really easy to create basic animations. Check the samples within the page.
I hope this helps! Regards bro

Comment: Here you can find nice examples showing how to use Shape Shifter: https://medium.com/@naththeprince/delightful-animations-in-android-d6e9c62a23d3